# Can I create a custom nib for UnknownPersonViewController without using an "undocumented api"?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I'd like to add some custom buttons to an ABUnknownPersonView. Can I use `initWithNibName:bundle:` in my ABUnknownPersonViewController to load a custom view that I've created in IB, while not using an "undocumented api?"  And if I do, how can I make sure that it follows all the properties and responds to all the hooks that the controller expects?

I typically create all my views programmatically and I generally like the view that `ABUnknownPersonViewController` creates.  I'd rather just start from there. And so I accessed the view and dropped in a button, but with later versions of iOS that broke since that isn't a hook that Apple created.

`initWithNibName` is also not mentioned in the `ABUnknownPersonViewController` documentation but it is a method of it's parent class `UIViewController`. Does that make it safe to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide a replacement XIB. While I understand you want to avoid it, you will have to use the underlying `AddressBook` framework and building your own version out of it.

You can, of course, look at open source stuff such as [`this`](https://github.com/samsoffes/sspersonviewcontroller) for a good starting point.

Comment: Great Thanks. Your search skills are better than mine. I couldn't for the life of me find a clone.